# html5 css padding-top inline code cant overwrite

Tags: css, html, inline-code

I have been trying to overwrite the ul html element tag to padding-top:30% instead of 50%. But unfortunately I am unable to overwrite. I tried manually in inspect element and I get the desired output.

Please have a look at the screenshot to understand better.

I have tried adding the code:

1) Directly in inline ul tag.
2) In the  tag 
3) and also, in Css using !important to override the css property.

[image: This is what currently the slider padding-top set as 50%]

[image: This is what I want after overriding the padding-top property to 30%]

I guess its quite simple and silly. But I dont have much coding experience with css.

Comment: are u using some framework like bootstrap ?

Comment: its just a js slider. And no I am not using bootstrap for this slider.

Comment: Well, I guess you either drop the inline code and use an `id` or `class` or some `css` identifier or you can do it via javascript.

Comment: The problem is I dont know where is that inline-code itself :/ I cant find the code anywhere. its in element.style in inspect element. so it has to be in head tag of html tag or directly in the tag itself. So I suggest someone help me override the code using !important. but I wasnt able to do that successfully

Comment: If it's not in the tag itself, it could be added by a script. So you should check those also.

Comment: `#ninja-slider > .slider-inner > ul {padding-top: 30% !important;}`